# Can't assign roles in admin panel

Tags: 7, users

The day before yesterday I created a new role (writers), and when, after adding quite a few modules, I wanted to add another earlier today, I discovered there was no way for me to do this anymore, nor to edit the role I already created. Now, I am a newby with Drupal, only started out about 4 days ago, so I probably (un)ticked a box somewhere I shouldn't have, so I hope someone can help me out figuring out how to change this?

I added a screenshot of the page I think the possibility to administer roles should be. :)
[image: screenshot]([link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOahd.png))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're on `/admin/people/permissions`, which is the page for configuring permissions per role. You want to be on `/admin/people/permissions/roles`, which is the page for configuring the roles themselves. If you can access `/admin/people/permissions/roles`, you'll be able to add more roles there.

If you get an 'Access Denied' error when you try to access that page:

1. Go back to `/admin/people/permissions`.
2. Make sure you've given the 'administrator' role all permissions.
3. Go to `/user`.
4. Click the 'Edit' tab.
5. Scroll down and make sure your account has the role 'administrator'.